# PGP Encryption Hanging From SQL

Tags: sql, pgp

I'm trying to use the code below to encrypt a file through sql, however the command hangs.
It does create a temporary file. The key is RSA.

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000),
        @FileName varchar(1000),
        @keyname varchar(1000),
        @trust varchar(50)

SET @cmd ='pgp -e \Alpha\c$\temp\BATCH.csv JohnSmith@myemail.com'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Any idea what could be causing it to freeze ?

Comment: Are you able to run that command on the command line of the server? Perhaps pgp is asking for a passphrase or some unexpected prompt that is causing the procedure to hang?

Comment: Thanks!, it was hanging on key trust.